# How to enable php execution on a web server in virtual host config file

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

How to enable php execution on a web server in virtual host config file?  I am on a VPS.  phpmyadmin is working which means I have php installed and working.

I am getting the error message

```
 client denied by server configuration: phpinfo.php

Forbidden  You don't have permission to access phpinfo.php on this server. Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at abc.com Port 80
```

Comment: On wich user does your apache run? Which user/group does the file have? Have you tried chmod +x phpinfo.php?

Answer (score 0):

verify your

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

line Allow from 127.0.0.1
Add your IP.

Also verify files and folders permision and group

(ls -l to www to phpinfo.php etc...)